# How to get id from a table and insert in another table in php statement?

Tags: php, mysqli

How to get id from stores and insert into another table with prepare statement ?

Do I have to do 2 queries?

Can anyone show an example please?

images table look like this

```
image_id image_name
```

items table

```
id item_name
```

my insert codes

```
    if(empty($title_err) && empty($details_err) && empty($image_err) && empty($cat_id_err)){
        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO adverts (cat_id, store_id, user_id, title, details, image, seo_url, hits, date, active) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,? ,?)";
        if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("iiissssiss", $param_cat_id, $param_store_id, $param_user_id, $param_title, $param_details, $param_image, $param_seo_url, $param_hits, $param_date, $param_active);

            // Set parameters
            $param_cat_id = htmlspecialchars($cat_id);
            $param_store_id = htmlspecialchars($store_id);
            $param_user_id = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['id']);
            $param_title = htmlspecialchars($title);
            $param_details = htmlspecialchars($details);
            $param_image = htmlspecialchars($filedestination);
            $param_seo_url = seo_url($title);
            $param_hits = htmlspecialchars(1);
            $param_date = htmlspecialchars($date);
            $param_active = htmlspecialchars(Y);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        $stmt->close();
    }

    // Close connection
    $conn->close();
}
```

I want to get id from stores table and insert into adverts

I did second query like below but it didn't work

```
// Prepare a select statementwhere userid=?
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM stores WHERE store_id=? ORDER BY store_id DESC";
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $param_store_id);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            if($result->num_rows == 1){
                /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                // Retrieve individual field value
                $store_id = $row["store_id"];
                $store_name = $row["store_name"];
            } else{
                // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                header("location: error.php");
                exit();
            }
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    $stmt->close();

    // Close connection
    $conn->close();
```

Comment: Your question is both unclear and too broad and contains no code. Can you post something that you tried where it may have failed you? That way it would have at least shown some effort on your part. Remember, we're always glad to help those who first help themselves. Speaking of "help"; you should go over the help area to familiarize yourself with what can and cannot be asked and what is expected of you https://stackoverflow.com/help  - By doing this, will **greatly improve** your experience on Stack Overflow.

Comment: main question edited and codes added, I did 2 querries separetly insert and selecet @Funk Forty Niner

Comment: If you need even more pointers on how to write a question that gets answers, you should make your code an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: lol. that is what I did all codes up there, dont know how to do in statments, was easy with mysqli